# Missing dropbox applet indicator. How do I get it back?

Tags: 14.04, icons, dropbox

Dropbox icons missing from top panel. Reinstalling doesn't fix this problem.

But Dropbox daemon is work perfectly and i can confirm it was running. How can I get an applet indicator for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is install `libappindicator1`, use the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Restart may necessary.

Comment: require a restart ? And thanks for fast response

Comment: Yeah somehow it need to restart for the effect